# How to specify image resources for 4" screen?

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6, iphone-5

In the Xcode I have like this:

[image: screenshot]

In a `MyViewController.m` I am loading the image and nicely it is loaded the @2x when needed ( on retina)

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"emptyList.png"]];
```

I would like to add another file which would be loaded only on the iPhone 5's 4" screen. Is that possible? How can I do it?

Comment: err... what?  "loading the image and nicely it is loaded". Not just the grammar, I don't get what your asking for.

Comment: You mean, add other files, like @3x.png, for example, and use it as the emptyList.png file?

Comment: I edit his question to be clearer.

Comment: I would like to have an emptyList_sufix_here@2x.png and when is running my code on iphone 5, than it would be load that file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is not very clear but what I am assuming you are asking is: What is the naming convention for iPhone 5 specific images?

We already know we can target iPad/iPhone and the retina/standard display of those devices using the:

```
.png
@2x.png
~iphone.png
~ipad.png
```

etc.

Well the question about iPhone 5 specific images has been discussed at length on the Apple Developer Forums, and it's clear there is no way to do this.

Notably, one clue was that the Default.png file to trigger 4" compatible apps had to be named `Default-568h@2x.png` which triggered a lot of devs thinking that adding the suffix "-568h@2x.png" was the way to go. It's not. You can find this discussion [here](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/166421?tstart=0) on the Apple Developer Forums.

Usually people look for this as a solution hoping to adapt for the larger screen with larger images. However, you should implement iOS 6's **AutoLayout** feature. Remember the iPhone 5's OS is at min iOS 6, you can also implement your layout with springs and struts otherwise.

This should be sufficient for scaling to the larger screen. If you wish to have a different layout altogether for the larger screen, you can detect the screen size and adapt accordingly. You can also specify in Xcode a different nib file to use on the 4" screen. Hope this helps.

More info on this [thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/166642?tstart=15) from the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: +1 nice answer, but I need to add support for an existing project ( ios5 and iphone3, iphone4) to ios6, iphone5 and hold the others. I am not sure I can use the AutoLayout, because I can't drop the ios5 support. Using the same xib file, will result a messy code, where I am checking if I am on a 4" device or just a smaller one, new xib files seems to be the best options. Thanks

Comment: Sure, new files is the way for you in this situation. I updated a few of my apps, I didn't change the design for the taller screen, and I didn't use nibs in those projects, it was a case of adjusting the height of my root view controllers etc I should have used `autoresizeMask` on my views but I didn't. This is what I mean by springs and struts, make anything you can autosize to the superview. You don't need to provide iPhone 5 specific images as a general rule.